# Sending an email with android not sending one

Tags: android

I am trying to send an email to a user with Android which will include a code. For whatever reason, it does not work.

I have followed [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-send-email-in-android-using-intent) tutorial

What is the problem?

This is the code:

```
public class PWReset extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText getMail;
    Button Continue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pwreset);

        getMail=findViewById(R.id.Mail);
        Continue=findViewById(R.id.PWR2);
        Continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String Code = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 5);

                //After checking if the email is registered in the DB
                resetPassword(getMail.getText().toString(), Code);

                Intent intent = new Intent(PWReset.this, PWReset2.class);

                intent.putExtra("code", Code);

                startActivity(intent);



            }
        });
    }


    public void resetPassword(String Mail, String code){
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{getMail.getText().toString()});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Password reset");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "You have requested a password reset.\nHere is the code for resetting your password:" + code +
                "\nIf you have not requested a password reset, ignore this message.");
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "gmail"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what does not work exactly? And why starting that activity PWReset2?

Comment: @blackapps Sending an email isn't working (resetPassword()), for whatever reason, it isn't sending an email with the code. Despite me putting correct information in.

Comment: Sorry but we knew that already. Only telling 'not working'' does tell nothing. And PWReset2? Why not reacting?